How to print echo command's output and a function's output side by side in same line?
I am trying to output a diamond shape with the following bash script.
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please write a number: " number

# Printing asterisks according to input:
for i in $(seq 1 "$number")
do
        stars+="*"
done

# Another way:
# stars=$(printf "%*s" "$number" "*")

# Function 1
space=$(( number - 1 ))
function pyramid1 {
        for (( i=1; i<=$number; i++ ))
        do
                for (( k=$space; k>=0; k-- ))
                do
                        echo -n " "
                done
                for (( j=1; j<=i; j++ ))
                do
                        echo -n "*"
                done
                space=$(( space - 1 ))
                echo
        done
}
# pyramid1

# output1=$(pyramid1)
# pyramid3=$(echo "$output1" | rev)
# echo "$pyramid3"

function pyramid4 {
for (( i=$number; i>0; i-- ))
do
  echo "$stars"
  until=$(( $i-1 ))
  stars="${stars:0:i-1}"
done
}

output=$(pyramid4)
pyramid2=$(echo "$output" | tac)

output1=$(pyramid1)
pyramid3=$(echo "$output1" | tac)

#pyramid1
#echo "$pyramid2"
#echo "$pyramid3"
#pyramid4


#echo "$pyramid2" > temp2
#echo "$pyramid3" > temp3

printf '%s|%s\n' "$(pyramid1)" "$pyramid2"
printf '%s|%s\n' "$pyramid3" "$(pyramid4)"

As a beginner, I was able to create each 4 parts. However I was not able to print each two parts side by side in the same line. I would really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance! Here is the output I am getting lastly 

using output is very inefficient because spawns subshells, it would be better to use printf -v varname ... and working with variables

out= ; for i in {4..1} {1..4};{ printf -v var '%*s%*s%-*s' $i '*' $[(4-i)*2] '' $i '*' ; out+=$var$'\n';}; echo "$out" 

Don't post images or links in questions, just text. We can't copy/paste an image to test with and not everyone will be willing/able to go clicking around other pages to piece your question together to be able to help you.

What you're doing in your question is manipulating text. Shells aren't intended for manipulating text, they're intended for manipulating (creating/destroying) files and processes and sequencing calls to other tools. The mandatory POSIX (available on all Unix boxes) tool for manipulating text is awk so if you really wanted to write a concise, portable, efficient bash script to manipulate text then the bash part would just be to call awk and then awk would do the rest. So, do you want help to do THAT or is this just an exercise for you in learning bash constructs?

Hmmm... Consider printf -v stars '%*s' $number;stars="${stars// /*}";echo "$stars"

It's hard to tell how to correlate the question with the code presented.  In fact, I suspect that you have framed the question incorrectly.  Your two functions, function1 and function4, both emit output that ends with a newline and may contain internal newlines, so what does it even mean to print that on the same line with something else?

For me, the question is not clear. As others have said, you can do a certain amount of string manipulation in the shell, and construct character sequences "piecewise" that way. It is also possible to output multiple shell variables at the same time - echo $part1 $part2. It is also possible to consume two (or more) input lines from a shell pipe and print them on a single output line - echo ... | paste - - (paste command).

Something like: read -pNumber:\  number;p1=$(star=;for ((i=number;i--;));do star+='*';printf '%*s\n' $number "$star";done );paste -d ''  <(echo "$p1") <(rev <<< "$p1") | tee >(sleep .1;tac);sleep .2

But for drawing a diamond, I would read -pNumber:\  number;printf -v stars '%*s' $((2*number));stars="${stars// /*}";str='';while [[ $str != "$stars" ]];do str+='**';printf '%*s\n' $((number+${#str}/2)) "$str";done;while [[ $str ]];do printf '%*s\n' $((number+${#str}/2)) "$str";str=${str:2}; done or better: read -pNumber:\  number;printf -v stars '%*s' $((1+2*number));stars="${stars// /*}";str='*';while [[ $str != "$stars" ]];do printf '%*s\n' $((1+number+${#str}/2)) "$str";str+='**';done;while [[ $str ]];do printf '%*s\n' $((1+number+${#str}/2)) "$str";str=${str:2};done

please update the question with expected outputs where number=3 and number=4; it's not clear (to me) how you can create a diamond with an even number of stars .... unless 'number' refers to something else (other than the max number of stars to be displayed in the center line)

Using a mixture of arithmetic evaluation (e.g., ((a=i<0?-i:i)) for absolute value of i), pattern substitution (e.g., "${s:0:b}" for b first characters of "$s") and the field width specification of printf (e.g., printf -v s '%*s' $((2*n)) '' to store a 2*n spaces string in s):
n=5
printf -v s '%*s' $((2*n)) ''
s=${s// /*}
for ((i=-n+1;i<n;i++)); do
  ((a=i<0?-i:i))
  ((b=2*(n-a)-1))
  printf '%*s%s\n' $a "" "${s:0:b}"
done
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
 *******
  *****
   ***
    *

